# How to copy files in Python without `os.rename` or `shutil`?

Tags: python, file, operating-system, shutil, file-copying

I have some photos and some videos that I have to copy them in another folder without using `shutil` and `os.rename`.  I can’t use shutil and os.rename because this is a condition for that Python exercise. I tried `open` but it only worked for text and not photos and videos.

Comment: which os are you using ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

open file in binary mode, and write in binary mode

```py
original_file = open('C:\original.png', 'rb') # rb = Read Binary
copied_file = open('C:\original-copy.png', 'wb') #wb = Write Binary

copied_file.write(original_file.read())

original_file.close()
copied_file.close()
```

[Python File Documentation](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/python-read-write-file)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```py
from pathlib import Path

Path("old_file.png").write_bytes(Path("new_file.png").read_bytes())
```