# How to copy a file without using shutil.copy

Tags: python, shutil, python-os

My teacher gave us a task:
I gotta create 2 folders: folder1 folder2
And i gotta add a text file to folder1
then append asmthg on it (iknow i use f = open("//Folder1//text.txt", mode = a, encoding = "UTF-8) then f.append("Hello World!")
and then i gotta copy the text file in folder1 to folder2 as text.txt(Copy) without using shutil.copyfile

So can anyone help about it?

Comment: You can read the context of the file (using `open`) and then you can write the same content in a new file in folder 2 (again, open it with the `open` built-in function)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to copy files in python without os.rename and shutil library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69423254/how-to-copy-files-in-python-without-os-rename-and-shutil-library)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `.txt` file you can always read it this way:

```
with open("file.txt", 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()
```

and write to a file this way:

```
with open("otherfile.txt", 'w') as otherfile:
    otherfile.write(content)
```

So this is the easier way to duplicate a file, since [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) with option `'w'` (write mode) will automatically create the file if it doesn't exist.

---

In your case, since you have paths like `r'\\Folder1\\text.txt'` you just have to replace "file.txt" with your path, this way:

```
with open("\\Folder1\\text.txt", 'r') as file:
    ...
with open("\\Folder2\\text.txt", 'w') as newfile:
    ...
```